# Revert saved changes to ActiveRecord objects ('versioning')?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

we're currently developing an app, where users shall be able to create and modify geopoints with names, address, description, etc. on a crowdsourced map. Changes made by guest users (everyone not signed in) are saved with a *reviewed flag* indicating that the changes applied have not been reviewed and hence will not be finally written to the DB. These records then shall become *reviewed* later on by authorized users.

Question is, how to realise some sort of simple versioning system, so that an authorized user can revert changes previously made to a record setting it to its original state? Is there some fancy "rails way" around duplicating the respective DB records?

Thanks in advance,
Andi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem.

*Track changes to your models, for auditing or versioning. See how a model looked at any stage in its lifecycle, revert it to any version, or restore it after it has been destroyed.*

Comment: Thanks, gonna have a look at this!